# Onclick validate edittext if user enters an int with a string

Tags: java, android

I have in my application an EditText which validates that the user cannot enter a integer when the user clicks a button.

This is done by an if statement on a condition where word is a String:

(word.matches("[0-9]*")

How can I change this if a user enters a word with a string as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An `EditText` inherits from a `TextView`, which has a method called [setInputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29). This method accepts an int defined as [InputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html). So you can set the `InputType` dynamically depending on what you want/the user clicks

Answer (score 0):

To do this kind of filter in EditText, the better way is to specify the [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType). This allow you to specify what you expect and also to display the right keyboard.
Another option is to use [android:digit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adigits) to specify the autorized characters. If you need numeric, enter

> android:digit="0123456789"

Comment: this validates to only allow the user to enter text. But the user can enter int and string such as hello123 I want only string no numbers. Thanks